# Check if user is coming from a another page

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to this, but i need something in javascript made very simple. I have a blog channel where i earn money from shortning links, only problem is everyone is bypassing them but on the site itself i can write javascript code for my monitized links.

So i need way when the user (visitor) is trying to bypass my monitized link on one of those bypass sites it needs to checks if they are coming from a certain domain like ‘thebypasser.com’ ‘linkvertisebypasser.com’ etc. If so throw them back with a error to my website blog.

I'd appreciate it very much if anyone could help me out here

No experience in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user comes from a specific website (say, `google.com`), the request has `Referer: https://www.google.com/` header

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer

This is generally the only information you can obtain from user's browser (the server-side of as website can share some more info)

Comment: Appreciate the anwser!